# Storing a ssh connection

Tags: python, ssh, pickle, paramiko, shelve

Lets say I have 6 servers and I'm connecting to all of them using `paramiko.SSHClient()` objects. I have 6 `paramiko.SSHClient()` objects corresponding to these 6 servers.
The problem is, the setting up of all these connections takes me roughly 30 seconds. Also I need to make these connections often. Everytime I try to connect, I have to wait 30 seconds. Is there a way to store these `SSHClient()` objects? I've tried storing them using persistent dictionary of `shelve` module but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle lock objects
```

So, is there any other way I can store these ssh connections(paramiko connection objects) persistently for future use?

Comment: You want to store an established connection? How do you expect that to work on the network layer?

Comment: You can't save an ssh session to reload in another process. Security depends on the session establishment handshake. That said, 30 seconds? It should be less than a second per session and you could do those in parallel in multiple threads. Something is amiss in your network or perhaps your code.

Comment: Actually, there is another process that has to be executed before I establish the connection. So the combined process takes 30 seconds

Comment: I understand that we can't store the connection. So is there any other way to optimise this? The new connections take far too long to connect.

Comment: What exactly is taking 30 seconds before you connect? Can the result of *that* be saved?